# Login Page with angularjs without angular-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a login page with angularjs and MVC controller(route) but here I don't want to use angular routing mechanism, actually what I want is that from the login page when I click on login(submit) button, then my page should redirect to the other page(home page). basically I am sending the http request to the MVC controller and when the user is identified then I am redirecting to a particular page through mvc redirect method, but when this happens angular http receives this response and there I have a problem to replace that with the entire page. how do I do that. can someone help me here. Please I don't want to use the angular route services here at all.
Below is the code for my test environment.
html:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'
  angular.module("GAiiNSApp").controller("Security", ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.user = {
        UserName: '',
        PWd: ''
      };


      $scope.LoginError = '';

      $scope.Login = function() {
        debugger;

        $http({
          url: '/Security/Account/Login',
          method: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify($scope.user),
          header: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(function(res) {
//Here is the problem how to replace the receive content with entire page. how to redirect the page to home on success 
        })
      };

    }
  ]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="~/Areas/Security/Controllers/NGSecurity/SecurityCtrl.js"></script>

<div id="LoginPlaceholder" layout="row" ng-controller="Security" style="margin-top:15%;" layout-padding layout-align="center start">

  <form flex="40" layout-margin name="userForm" ng-submit="Login()" novalidate>
    <md-card layout-padding style="background-color:#20735e; border-radius:10px; ">


      <md-card-title-text style="font: 16px; color:white; text-align:center; font-family:  'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;">
        <span class="md-headline ">GFI LOGIN</span>
      </md-card-title-text>

      <md-content flex="100">
        <br />
        <br />
        <md-input-container layout-gt-xs="row" class="md-block" layout-align="space-between start">
          <label>User Name</label>
          <md-icon style="fill:#20735e;" md-svg-icon="~/Content/myIcons/action/svg/production/ic_account_circle_48px.svg"></md-icon>

          <input name="UserName" ng-model="user.UserName" type="text" ng-required="true">
          <div ng-messages="userForm.UserName.$error" role="alert" multiple>
            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must provide GAiiNSPlus user name to login.</div>

          </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container layout-gt-xs="row" class="md-block" layout-align="space-between start">
          <label>Password</label>

          <md-icon style="fill:#20735e;" md-svg-icon="~/Content/myIcons/action/svg/production/ic_vpn_key_48px.svg"></md-icon>
          <input name="pass" ng-model="user.PWd" type="password" minlength="4" md-minlength="4" ng-required="true">
          <div ng-messages="userForm.pass.$error" role="alert" multiple>
            <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">You must provide GAiiNSPlus password to login.</div>
            <div ng-message="pattern" class="my-message">Password must be minimum four digits.</div>
          </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <br />
        <br />
        <md-divider></md-divider>

        <div layout="row" layout-align="end start">
          <md-button type="submit" class="md-icon-float md-block md-raised" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">
            Login
          </md-button>
        </div>

        <hr />

      </md-content>
    </md-card>
  </form>


</div>
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(secUser U)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(U.UserName, U.PWd))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(U.UserName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Area = "Common" });
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Msg"] = "Login Failed";

                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = "Login Failed" + ex.Message;
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

    }
```

Comment: why would you use ajax call then, if you can use standard form submit mechanism? Or am I missing something....

Comment: **Vladimir M**, I was using this jQuery ajax, but I want to get rid of the jQuery and use only angularjs. so is it possible that we can do it with angularjs.

Comment: Well... it seems to me that you are aiming for standard form functionality (i.e. submit always takes you to a different page). In this case, just add an action to form itself as described in http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp for example.

Comment: **Vladimir**, I think you are talking about the page to post on the data, but I am talking about the page to redirect after successful authentication.

Comment: **Vladimir**, did you get my point what I am trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was saying in comments, since you seem to always do some sort of redirection on login (back to login or to home) by your MVC controller, then you can as well use form's action to do the trick.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ewu83nORY6qYLN7dW6m4?p=preview

Here in index.html I am setting a basic form. I am using get as a method just cause I dont have a server to post to. But you will be using post.

```
<form action="do_magic.html" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="id"></input>
  <button type="submit"> submit </button>
</form>
```

What happens is that form is submitted to url 'do_magic.html' and browser will display the content that server sends in response.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=redirected.html" />
</head>
</html>
```

What I do, is I use html meta to redirect. In your case, your server will probably send an appropriate header for it.

After getting the content on form submit, browser will redirect to "redirected.html"

The difference between my example and your target problem is that your server will do some smart processing instead of (do_magic.html)

Alternatively, use window.location as it is done here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Ck3Hp2g8hJiqNGd9KCBV?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.go_google=function(){
    window.location="test.html";
  }
});
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: **Vladimir M**, how does it fit into angularjs with mvc controller. Did not get your code to understand.

Comment: That is my point. If you always do a redirect to the entire new page, then you don't need angular help. You just do a standard form submit and it is your server, that completes the redirect.

Comment: otherwise, just use: window.location="new url";

Comment: is it possible to use windows.location with angularjs. can you show any working code.

Comment: yes. https://plnkr.co/edit/Ck3Hp2g8hJiqNGd9KCBV?p=preview : angular is just a framework. window object is part of core javascript.